# Dynamically creating buttons with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, leaflet

I currently have a Leaflet map that reads in a shapefile, and plots polygons on this map. When you click a polygon, a pop-up box appears.  This works just fine. The next step is to add 2 buttons to some of the pop-up windows when you click a polygon. 

 I also have a JSON file that each entry contains a key(OBJECTID, read on), then a previous and a next field.
This is how the JSON file will be used,
Each polygon is an object that contains properties. One of these properties is called OBJECTID. So I want to check when I am plotting these polygons, if the polygon's OBJECTID == a key in the JSON file, then I want to include these two buttons in the pop-up box.

Now that you are confused, here is the code:

```
 //adding shapefiles to the map
 var shpfile = new L.Shapefile('Corinth-1.zip',     {onEachFeature:function(feature, layer) {
  if (feature.properties) 
  { 
   //this looks at the object's properties and prints them all out in a popup box
   layer.bindPopup(Object.keys(feature.properties).map(function(k)
    {
      return k + ": " + feature.properties[k] ;
    }).join("<br />"),{maxHeight:200});
    //if feature.properties.OBJECTID exists in JSONFILE
    {
       //***make two buttons*****/
       //first I need to pull the other two columns from the JSON file where JSONFILE.key == OBJECTID and save them as variables for use in my buttons.
       //var prev = ?
       //var next = ? 
    }
  }
 }});
     shpfile.addTo(map);
     shpfile.once("load", function(){
      console.log("finished loaded shapefile");
     });
```

I am stuck when it comes to 
1) checking if the OBJECTID is a key in the JSON file.
2) setting two varaibles, next and previous equal to the other fields of the JSON file

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: is your json file already loaded ? if yes, whats the variable name?

Comment: it is not loaded yet but lets just say it is called objTable

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I assume your json looks something like this (if it's an array):

```
[
    {key: 100, prev: "prevField1", next: "nextField1"},
    {key: 101, prev: "prevField2", next: "nextField2"},
    ...
]
```

You could then prepare your json to make it more comfortable to work with:

```
var preparedTable = {};

for(var i = 0; i < objTable.length; i++) {
  var entry = objTable[i];
  preparedTable[entry.key] = entry;
}
```

Your json then exists in the form

```
{
  100: {key: 100, prev: "prevField1", next: "nextField1"},
  101: {key: 101, prev: "prevField2", next: "nextField2"},
  ...
}
```

So you can use it like this

```
// if the key exists
if(preparedTable[feature.properties.OBJECTID]) {
  // read prev and next values
  var prev = preparedTable[feature.properties.OBJECTID].prev;
  var next = preparedTable[feature.properties.OBJECTID].next;

  // create prev button
  var btnPrev = document.createElement('button');
  btnPrev.setAttribute('class', 'anyClass');
  btnPrev.innerHTML = prev;

  // create next button
  var btnNext = document.createElement('button');
  btnNext.setAttribute('class', 'anyClass');
  btnNext.innerHTML = next;

  // this assumes you have already a popup with the id "popup"
  // dynamically append buttons to popup
  var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
  popup.appendChild(btnPrev);
  popup.appendChild(btnNext);
}
```

So if the key from `features.properties.OBJECTID` exists in the object `preparedTable`, the `prev` and `next` values are read from it and two buttons are created, whose contents are set to the `prev` and `next` values and the buttons get appended to the popup with the id `popup`.

Let me know if this helped or if I made wrong assumptions.